# wget not following redirect 301

Tags: wget

I want to get multi website for offline use, with limited level( somewhat like mirror). Some of these websites have WWW in their URL like http://1developer.net and some of them has not.
When using wget to mirror these websites, It stooped after redirect and does'n continue download all pages.

```
wget -m -nH --no-clobber --timeout=30 --random-wait -N --tries=10 --convert-links --no-parent  -r -E -e robots=off --restrict-file-names=ascii -Q 20m -U mozilla --level=3 -P /home/webs/1dev"/" http://www.1developer.net
```